# difference in the return type of date value from stored procedure using jdk8 and spring boot 1.5.3 and jdk21 and spring boot 2.7.16

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc, simplejdbccall

The response of executing stored procedure is returning different return type

In jdk 8 and spring boot 1.5.3-RELEASE it is coming as ScheduledStartDate=1704479400000

and in jdk 21 and spring boot 2.7.16 it is returning as ScheduledStartDate=2024-01-06 17:00:00.0

after executing the procedure as below from java

```
Map<String, Object> result = simpleJdbcCall.execute(sqlParameter);
```

stored procedure as below

```
     BEGIN
                SELECT *
                FROM WorkOrder
                WHERE (RowNo BETWEEN @PageSize * (@PageNumber - 1) + 1 AND @PageNumber * @PageSize)
                   OR (RowNo = 0 AND FromDate >= @FromDate AND FromDate < @Todate)
                ORDER BY DeliveryDate, status, WorkOrderID, FromDate

        END
```

I downgraded the MS SQL server driver from 12.4 to 6.4 still this issue is not resolved
Any one faced similar issues or why the return type is different ?

Answer (score 0):

finally found that the issue is due to jackson serializer. adding the below line in the application properties helped me

spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps=true